# Printing star with recursive function in java

Tags: java, for-loop, recursion

I am confused about how printStarNTimes(count) is printing * in reverse order. Please help me to understand. Why second printStarNTimes(count) increase its count value. I want to print star

```
public static void printStars(int count){
        if (count == 0){
            return;
        }
        printStarNTimes(count);
        printStars(count-1);

     //printing * in reverse order. 
    printStarNTimes(count);
}

    private static void printStarNTimes(int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

input is:

```
printStars(5);
```

output is :

```
*****
****
***
**
*
*
**
***
****
*****
```

[recursive function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HkG5.png)

Comment: please post input and output here

Comment: [No image of code, errors or output](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) please. Thanks.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

The second printStarNTimes is exactly the same as the first:

```
printStarNTimes(count); //Count = 4

//Recersive call with count -1
printStars(count-1);

printStarNTimes(count); //Count still = 4
```

It prints in reverse order because the first `printStarNTimes` of each recursive method is always printed before the second call to `printStarNTimes`. This is a normal order or code, the recursive code inside `printStars(count-1);` must finish before the second `printStarNTimes` can be printed.

For example, if the count was 3 then here is what is happening in order:

```
printStarNTimes(count); //prints ***
printStars(count-1); //recursive call with count = 2
    printStarNTimes(count); //prints **
    printStars(count-1); //recursive call with count = 1
        printStarNTimes(count); //prints *
        printStars(count-1); //recursive call with count = 0
            return; //Nothing happens for count = 0
        printStarNTimes(count); //prints *
    printStarNTimes(count); //prints **
printStarNTimes(count); //prints ***
```

Notice how the count never changes for the second `printStarNTimes`, it appears in reverse simply because it prints after all previous recursive calls happen first because you call `printStars(count-1)` before the second print.

Comment: so if print statement use after recursive method then its print in reverse order?? so next statement will not start without finishing recurssion?

Comment: Correct. As each recursive method resolves and returns then the print statement after the call also resolves in order back through the recursion stack.